# Bouncycastle write cms MIME header in ascii/binary format

Tags: openssl, bouncycastle

I using bouncycastle c# to generate cms signed data file and my openSsl command is below

```
openssl cms -sign -in data.txt -binary -signer selfsigned.crt -inkey keypair.pem -out data.signed -keyopt rsa_padding_mode:pss
```

The output file form openssl

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/pkcs7-signature"; micalg="sha-256"; boundary="----DE5BACF44AD3EE95D349BA916BEEB444"

This is an S/MIME signed message

------DE5BACF44AD3EE95D349BA916BEEB444
Data HERE
------DE5BACF44AD3EE95D349BA916BEEB444
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"

SOME BASE 64 DATA
------DE5BACF44AD3EE95D349BA916BEEB444--

===============================================
```

BouncyCastle output is not that same, i.e the header written in ascii format, something like that

```
0€  *†H†÷
 €0€10
    `†He 0€ *†H†÷
 €$€‚

Data HERE

 €0€10
    `†He 0€ *†H†÷
 €$€‚ €0€10
    `†He 0€ *†H†÷
 €$€‚ €0€10
    `†He 0€ *†H†÷
 €$€‚ €0€10
    `†He 0€ *†H†÷
 €$€‚
```

How to get the same header like the openssl

BouncyCastle code for cms sign

```
void Sign(byte[] data, byte[] signCert, byte[] privateKey){
            X509CertificateParser parser = new X509CertificateParser();
            X509Certificate certificate = parser.ReadCertificate(signCert);
            var reader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(privateKey), Encoding.Default);
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
            CmsSignedDataGenerator generator = new CmsSignedDataGenerator();
            generator.AddSigner(keyPair.Private, certificate, CmsSignedGenerator.EncryptionRsaPss, 
            CmsSignedGenerator.DigestSha256);
            List<X509Certificate> certList = new List<X509Certificate>();
            certList.Add(certificate);
            CmsSignedData signedData = generator.Generate(CmsSignedGenerator.Data, new 
            CmsProcessableByteArray(data), true);
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\data.txt.signed", signedData.GetEncoded());
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

BouncyCastle won't produce those headers. You would need to do that yourself or use a library like [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) that will do it for you.

Comment: I was able to generate the signed file, but I have two concerns. First I want to set the MimeMessage Body to byte array, and when I try to verify the generate output with openssl it gives me failure with reasons

30080:error:2E09A09E:CMS routines:CMS_SignerInfo_verify_content:verification failure:crypto\cms\cms_sd.c:848:
30080:error:2E09D06D:CMS routines:CMS_verify:content verify error:crypto\cms\cms_smime.c:393:

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing so I can't tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: what about set mimemessage body as byte array ?

Comment: Create a MimePart and set the content to a MemoryStream with the byte array data. Then set the MimePart as the message body.

Comment: MimePart mimePart = new MimePart();
            mimePart.Content.Stream.Write(data); 
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage
            {
                Body = mimePart
            };

I did this but not working, or I might missing something?

Comment: `var mimePart = new MimePart ("type", "subtype") { Content = new MimeContent (new MemoryStream (byteArrayData)) };`

Comment: Keep in mind that the `MimePart` will add a `Content-Type` header to the `MimeMessage`, so make sure you choose the correct `type` and `subtype` strings. You may also want to set a `ContentDisposition` on the `MimePart` and possibly also a `ContentTransferEncoding`.

Comment: Setting a `ContentTransferENcoding` on the `MimePart` will encode the raw `MimeContent`, so don't base64 encode the `MimeContent` data - let the `ContentTransferEncoding` do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

After trying different libraries, but no luck, I figured a way to achieve this using BouncyCastle, I just needed to add the header manually and fixed the code to achieve it

```
public byte[] Sign(byte[] data, byte[] signCert, byte[] privateKey)
        {
            
            X509CertificateParser parser = new X509CertificateParser();
            X509Certificate certificate = parser.ReadCertificate(signCert);
            var reader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(privateKey), Encoding.Default);
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();

            CmsSignedDataGenerator generator = new CmsSignedDataGenerator();

            generator.AddSigner(keyPair.Private, certificate, CmsSignedGenerator.EncryptionRsaPss, CmsSignedGenerator.DigestSha256);

            List<X509Certificate> certList = new List<X509Certificate>
            {
                certificate
            };
            IX509Store iX509Store = X509StoreFactory.Create("Certificate/Collection", new X509CollectionStoreParameters(certList));
            generator.AddCertificates(iX509Store);

            CmsSignedData signedData = generator.Generate(CmsSignedGenerator.Data, new CmsProcessableByteArray(data), true);

            var signedBase64Encoded = Base64.Encode(signedData.GetEncoded());
            var signedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(signedBase64Encoded);
            signedString = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
                            + "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"smime.p7m\"\n"
                            + "Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data; name=\"smime.p7m\"\n"
                            + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n"
                            + Regex.Replace(signedString, "(.{" + 64 + "})", "$1" + Environment.NewLine);

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signedString);
        }
```